# Wordpress twig template shortcode not displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony Twig template with Wordpress, everything runs fine except that I can't get any shortcode to be displayed in a page template.

I'm trying to display a contact form with Contact form 7 plugin.

The shortcode is something like `[contact-form-7 id='1234' title='Contact']`
Even Wordpress default shortcode are not working.

Here is my code for page template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.post_title }}</h1>

    <div class="entry">
        {{ post.post_content|raw }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

If I replace

```
{{ post.post_content|raw }}
```

by this

```
{{ wp.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact"]') }}
```

I can see the contact form. But I don't want to write the shortcode in my template file.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the following should work!

> <strike>{{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content) }}</strike>

or,

> {{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content)|raw }}

or ,

> <strike>{{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content|raw ) }}</strike>

or

> <strike>{{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content|raw )|raw }}</strike>

***Updated***

Working Code Is :

> **{{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content)|raw }}**

Comment: This is working :
{{ wp.do_shortcode( post.post_content)|raw }}

I also tried to add extra html in the post content and it's rendering well :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
{{  post.post_content|shortcodes }}
```

And with custom fields

```
{{ customfield|shortcodes }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
    {{ wp.do_shortcode(' [email-subscribers') }}
{% endfilter %}
```

but the only HTML displayed not displayed Email subscribers form.

Comment: You forgot a ] on the right side of your shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to display short code in `twig` file

```
{% filter shortcodes %} [short_code id="1"] {% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I print Shortcode value in twig template like this way:

```
{% set contact_form = (contact_form.form is not empty) ? '[contact-form-7 id="' ~ contact_form.form ~ '"]' : '' %}
{{ function('do_shortcode', contact_form) }}
```