# Wordpress shortcode not working in twig page template

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I'm using Gantry5 framework (with the g5_hydrogen theme) and I created a twig page template which works fine, except the shortcode for the Contact Form 7 plugin apparently does nothing - the form does not display on the page, and when I inspect the element in my browser I just see some blank space between the div tags. My current markup is something like this:

```
{% block content %}
  <content>
    <div class="dbc-contact-form">
      {{ wp.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact"]') }}  
    </div>
  </content>
{% endblock %}
```

Someone else posted a similar question before, but unfortunately that solution doesn't help in my case - [Wordpress twig template shortcode not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757328/wordpress-twig-template-shortcode-not-displayed)

Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - {{  post.post_content|shortcodes }}

Comment: Can you put that in the context of the question please, such as modifying their code to show your example?